# Get Glassfish 4.1.1 from JMX

Tags: glassfish-3, jmx, glassfish-4

I wan to get Glassfish version from JMX using Java code. I tried to search in JConsole tool but still I can't find it is there any way to get this data?

Answer (score 1):

You could go with `serverVersion`. But as you can see in the picture, you still get `Glassfish V3.1` with Glassfish 4.1. 
[image: serverVersion screen]

Now, `ApplicationServerFullVersion` will bring better results: `GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  4.1  (build 13)`
[image: ApplicationServerFullVersion screen]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the GlassFish version from code not via JMX there is a Version class in package com.sun.appserv.server.util this has many version related methods; [See the source on GitHub](https://github.com/payara/Payara/blob/8a403bf75d3734e564a9fb95d60498987cc4287e/nucleus/common/common-util/src/main/java/com/sun/appserv/server/util/Version.java)